# NHibernate GenericAdoException was unhandled could not execute query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an exception "GenericAdoException was unhandled" could not execute query while i was trying to do the nhibernate example on this line:

```
var users = session.CreateCriteria<User>().List<User>();
```

Inner exception is: incorrect syntax near 'User'

My Main method on Program.cs:

```
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = "Server=.;database=NHibernateTryOutDB;uid=sa;pwd=Hasar2012";
                x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                x.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
            });
            cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var users = session.CreateCriteria<User>().List<User>();
                foreach (User item in users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Name, item.Surname);
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I ve a table named Users:

```
USE [NHibernateTryOutDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Users]    Script Date: 12/10/2013 16:04:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

My class names User.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class User
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My .hbm.xm file that is User.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="ConsoleApplication2"
                   namespace="ConsoleApplication2">
  <class name="User">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <property name="Surname"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: in hbm.xml, `<class name="User">` should be `<class name="User" table="Users">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User is a reserved word in sql, you need to add [] around user or choose a different name for your object. Besides that your table name is Users, instead of user from your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

First, check connecting database name, use correct database name in connection string.